# GCP Cloud SQL Query Logging for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've been struggling for a few weeks now to try and get a Cloud SQL Postgres instance to do any type of query logging and I'm just not getting anywhere with it. I realise that this should be a super simple exercise, but I just don't have any more of an explanation to give than it just doesn't seem to work.

I've tried setting the following flags:

`log_min_duration_statement` with values of 0, 100, 500 and 1000.

`log_statement` with values of 'ddl', 'mod' and 'all'.

`log_statement_stats` set to 'on'.

I've also tried a bunch of other "likely suspects" listed here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags to no avail.

I've even tried enabling the pgaudit logs, which didn't seem to do anything.

Given that, there's always a chance this data is being logged, but I'm just not finding it, so in stackdriver, my filter is:

```
resource.type="cloudsql_database"
resource.labels.database_id="<<project-name>>:<<instance-name>>"
```

Which shows me any errors that occur on the DB, like querying a table that doesn't exist, or attempting to compare two different data types, but no queries of any kind.

I've even gone as far as scanning all of our logs with:

```
textPayload:"select"
```

Which also doesn't turn up anything.

Any advice, tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Additional information.

The instance that I'm testing with is described in this image:
[image: Instance specs]

I'm able to create the pgaudit extension on all of my schemas without any errors. The psql client simply echoes back 'CREATE EXTENSION'.

I'm connecting to the instance using private IP, from a GKE environment, and my applications run both DDL & DML statements.

This is an image of the 'Audit Logs' I enabled for cloud SQL within the Access section of the cloud console:
[image: Audit logs enabled]

This is a brand new instance that I'm using for load testing, so each morning I create a new instance using a terraform script, here is the relevant resource:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "loadtesting_postgres_master" {
   database_version = "POSTGRES_12"
   name             = "loadtesting-test-instance-12"
   project          = "${var.projectId}"
   region           = "${var.region}"

   depends_on = ["google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection"]
   deletion_protection = false

   settings {

activation_policy = "ALWAYS"
availability_type = "ZONAL"

backup_configuration {
  binary_log_enabled             = "false"
  enabled                        = "true"
  location                       = "eu"
  point_in_time_recovery_enabled = "true"
  start_time                     = "03:00"
}

disk_autoresize        = "false"
disk_size              = "1000"
disk_type              = "PD_SSD"

ip_configuration {
  ipv4_enabled    = "true"
  private_network = "projects/my-project-name/global/networks/loadtesting-vpc"
  require_ssl     = "false"
}

location_preference {
  zone = "${var.region}"
}

maintenance_window {
  day  = "7"
  hour = "0"
}

pricing_plan     = "PER_USE"
tier             = "db-custom-8-15360"
  }
}
```

After the instance comes up, I manually add the two flags you've recommended, one at a time.

Manually create the pg audit extension on each of my schemas, and start running my tests.

Still nothing getting logged on stackdriver.

Comment: did you restart your server after doing all the steps?

Answer (score 5):

So it looks like you need to enable the [`pgaudit` flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/pg-audit). (Currently in beta)

To summarize the link:

```
INSTANCE_NAME=sql-playground
gcloud sql instances patch $INSTANCE_NAME --database-flags cloudsql.enable_pgaudit=on`
gcloud sql connect $INSTANCE_NAME
```

Once inside the DB, run this:

```
> CREATE EXTENSION pgaudit;
```

Then back in gcloud land:

```
gcloud sql instances patch $INSTANCE_NAME --database-flags \
  cloudsql.enable_pgaudit=on,pgaudit.log=all
```

It takes a restart or two and a few moments in between, but I did get it to log the statements:

[image]

Of course, be careful in production env, and with PII data, etc, etc.

Comment: Do you know if it exist the same "EXTENSION" trick with Cloud SQL MySQL database?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately - this doesn't seem to be working for me.
I've enabled both of the relevant Flags on the DB instance, I've created the extension on all of the schemas on the instance, and I've enabled all of the Audit logs for 'Cloud SQL' on this page: https://console.cloud.google.com/access/audit?project=<<project-name>>, but still nothing is getting logged out into stackdriver.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, maybe check [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/235216) for MySQL.

Comment: @DuncanGener8, I didn't have to do anything in Audit Logs to get that screen shot. I have no checks on that page for this project. Are you using PostgreSQL 12? And do you see the flags set in the Cloud SQL instance? Did the `CREATE EXTENSION pgaudit;`  command return properly?

Comment: @nomadic_squirrel
I am using PostgreSQL 14 and see these flags set in the Cloud SQL instance:
cloudsql.enable_pgaudit - on, pgaudit.log - all.
The `CREATE EXTENSION pgaudit` returned properly.
Still i can't see the queries in error logs in the Cloud Log Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Take into consideration that you'd need to enable [Data Access Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/audit-logging#audited_operations), nonetheless the logs are only written to Cloud Logging [if the operation is an authenticated user-driven API call](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/logging#audit-logging).

Although the product is still in Pre-GA Offering terms, I would recommend you to test the `pgaudit` extension as explained within the [relevant section of the public docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/pg-audit). The steps are quite simple, as  you should:

1. Enable the relevant flag on the instance by issuing `gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --database-flags cloudsql.enable_pgaudit=on`.
2. Use the command to create the extension within the instance (or particular database) by signing into the instance with the psql client with an user that has the cloudsqlsuperuser role: `CREATE EXTENSION pgaudit;`
3. Set the values for the pgaudit.log flag (e.g. to turn on all database operations within an instance: `gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --database-flags cloudsql.enable_pgaudit=on,pgaudit.log=all`).

Notice that depending on the load that your database receives enabling these flags might translate in [CPU and memory overload](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/logging#tuning-logging) so it might be wise to overprovision the tier assigned to the instance as per your current load and that enabling such logs could translate in an increase in Billing as you'd be able to see the logs within the `cloudaudit.googleapis.com/data_access` [Data access audit logs that are charged separately](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/audit-logging#pricing).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, unfortunately - this doesn't seem to be working for me.
I've enabled both of the relevant Flags on the DB instance, I've created the extension on all of the schemas on the instance, and I've enabled all of the Audit logs for 'Cloud SQL' on this page: https://console.cloud.google.com/access/audit?project=<<project-name>>, but still nothing is getting logged out into stackdriver.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any additional configuration to be taken in place. Would you mind posting some details to attempt a minimum, reproducible example of your while setup including PostgreSQL version, all the flags used, tier characteristics for the instance, exact way you are making the queries to the application, what type of queries you are using, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider verifying your user has the `roles/logging.privateLogViewer` "Private Logs Viewer" role.  Per https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#considerations :

```
roles/logging.privateLogViewer (Private Logs Viewer) includes roles/logging.viewer, plus the ability to read Access Transparency logs and Data Access audit logs in the _Required and _Default buckets.
```

We struggled a long time to figure out why we weren't seeing these logs ourselves, and it ended up being that the "Logs Viewer" role is insufficient to read these data access logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled below FLAGS from GCP console on my Postgres service and now able to generate all type of DB activity/query logs

```
cloudsql.iam_authentication
on
pgaudit.log
all
log_statement
all
```

[image]